# How to solve the crash when smart pointer uses the structure in the class？

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class CTest {
 public:
  struct StructTest {
    std::string StrTest;
  };
};
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<CTest::StructTest> opt;
  opt->StrTest = "hello world\n";
  std::cout << opt->StrTest;
  return 0;
}
```

This code is so simple, but it crashes. I can't understand why smart pointer can't use it like this.

Comment: @Rup Thank you for your reply. You can compile and run it.

Comment: Why did you use nested classes in your example code? Couldn't you have just written code like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1vccEv418)?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that `opt` is a pointer, but you do not initialize it to point to anything. It's a good habit to use `auto` to initialize smart pointers:

```
auto opt = std::make_shared<CTest::StructTest>();
```

Using `auto` like this ensures that you don't forget to initialize the pointer, because `auto opt;` will just not compile with modern C++, and you will immediately see it won't make any sense either.

Answer (score 2):

`opt` is just default-constructed, it points to nothing. Dereference on it leads to UB.

You can change the code to

```
std::shared_ptr<CTest::StructTest> opt = std::make_shared<CTest::StructTest>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I knew it, and I made a stupid mistake

Comment: Alternatively replace variable definition with `auto opt = ....` since the right side is pretty clear on what it is doing :)